# Android vs. iOS: which suits better for a money tracking app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm thinking about creating an app on mobile devices, which will deal with 'money saving', tracking your expenditures.
Something like [this one](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/spending-log/id428939317?mt=8)  (iOS)
or [this one](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.jg-finance-moneydroid-nxj.aspx)   (android).

I'm completely new to this field (even if I'm a quite experienced programmer in webapps with jquery, backbone, html5, couchdb etc.) but I guess that the two worlds (iOS and Android) actually adress to different users.

Does anybody knows about statistics (even simple suggestions are welcome) that can help me understanding if an app which tracks your expenditure is most suitable for iOS or Android?

Which are the differences in those two worlds?

Is iOS more suitable for entertainment app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea sounds like it does not require huge amount of computation... so why not hit both markets using one of many "one rock, multiple birds" solutions? Like Phonegap for example, which uses web code that your already experienced with. It does not sound like you need a performance boost from writing the native code.

From what I've seen, the general consensus is that iOS apps make in general "more profit" in comparison to Android. That statement is highly situation-based, and can't really blanket every type of app.

Answer (score 0):

Both OSes have a very high reach.
It is not what you asked, but I would recommand you to start coding for Android, then port your app to iOS.
Thanks to the play store policies you can do a lot of fine tuning to your app based on its usage and instantly push an update.